# mysqli_query undefined index notice

Tags: php

I have tried searching for an answer but so far nothing has worked, the below code works fine when $category has a value in the url but i want to display some code when it doesn't.

```
    $dynamicList = ""; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM product_catalog WHERE category='".$_GET['category']."'");     
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $id = $row["id"];
    $title = $row["title"];
    $price = $row["price"];
    $image = $row["image"];
    $product_code = $row["product_code"];
    $description = $row["description"];
    $dynamicList .= 'html code';
    }
    mysqli_close($con);  
    ?>
```

This is the last thing i have tried is below and that gives me hello on every page but still the error when category is not set.

```
    if($result != NULL){
    echo 'hello' ;
    }
    else
    {
    echo 'goodbye';
    }
```

My head is most likely fried from the amount of time I've been looking at this, if anyone can point me in the right direction i would be most grateful

Thanks.

Comment: $result will jet tell you of the query worked, not if there where any rows returned.

Comment: First, sort out the SQL injection problem. Then, consider whether `$_GET['category']` might give an undefined index error if the `category` index on the `$_GET` array happens to be undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just check if category exists?

```
if(isset($_GET['category'])) {
    //yourcode
}
```

Oh and before I forget, you should also sanitize $_GET['category'] before running a query with it.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off testing for the existence of $_GET['category'] first, and running your database query only if it exists, and if it does not exist, running your alternate code.

Do something like

```
if(isset($_GET['category'])){
    //your database query
}
else{
     //your alternate code
}
```

This way you won't run the query when you don't have to.

You should also consider learning PDO. It will help take care of the sql injection problem everybody is talking about.

Comment: MySQLi can do prepared statements too; you don't *need* PDO. Though it's good, of course.